# How do you send an attachment with sendmail?

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

How do you send an attachment with sendmail?  I'm able to send an email with the below:

```
sendmail johndoe@example.com < email.txt
```

I can't find out how to send one with an attachment, I've tried:

```
sendmail johndoe@example.com < email.txt -a foo.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `sendmail` works. It just deals with transporting the mail and expects a properly encoded mail already.

You could do this encoding yourself or just use `mail/mailx/mutt` instead to hand over a suitable mail over to `sendmail` for delivery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `uuencode` to encode the attachment.
**Most** email clients recognize uuencoded attachments.

Make sure there is an empty line after email headers in email.txt file.  Sendmail expects "raw" message.

```
#!/bin/sh
(cat email.txt; uuencode foo.pdf foo.pdf)|/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- johndow@example.com
```

Comment: Related answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507171/61742 .

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't call sendmail directly but use `mail` or `mailx` which will also help you set up the correct headers and such. Moderns version of those support adding attachments with the `-a` option.

The alternative, is to MIME (base645) encode your attachment and include it, with the correct headers in the body of your raw email text and submit that to sendmail.